# Get EmbeddedDocument's Parent Document's ID in MongoMapper

Tags: ruby, mongomapper

Suppose the following model.

```
class Person
  include MongoMapper::Document

  key :name, String
  key :surname, String

  many :children
end

class Child
  include MongoMapper::EmbeddedDocument

  key :name, String
end
```

Plus, the following query (with Sinatra):

```
get 'child/:id' do
  @child = Child.find(params[:id])
end
```

Is there a way to get the ID of the Person that that Child belongs to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is this:

```
class Child
  include MongoMapper::EmbeddedDocument

  embedded_in :parent
  key :name, String
end
```

I'm not quite sure how your query works - I'm not seeing that there's a find on the Child class since it's an EmbeddedDocument.  However:

```
Person.where("children._id" => params[:id]).first.parent
```

should work.

Comment: Don't you mean just `Person.where("children._id" => params[:id]).first`?  (Which btw can be abbreviated: `Person.first("children._id" => params[:id])`)

Comment: Yes - I didn't demonstrate properly.  I meant `Person.first("children._id" => params[:id]).children.first.parent == Person.first("children._id" => params[:id])`.